# Why is $B^{-1} A = B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be symmetric matrices, where $B$ is also positive definite.

How can I show that this holds: $$B^{-1} A = B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2}.$$

I'm only able to write: $$B^{-1} A = B^{-1/2} B^{-1/2} A.$$

How does the transpose come into play in the first equation above?

Comment: Your statement is not true.  Why do you believe that this holds?

Comment: You're right, I realized minutes after having posted this. So the original claim was that $B^{-1}A$ and $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ have the same eigenvalues. And I assumed that their eigenvectors should be the same as well, which isn't true. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement does not hold.  For instance, we find with 
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&\frac 12}, \quad A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$
that $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$ is symmetric, but $B^{-1}A$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

The two matrices are similar since

$$B^{-1} A = B^{-1/2}(B^{-1/2} A B^{-1/2})B^{1/2}.
,$$ so they have the same eigenvalues. But they dont need to be equal.